# How to move Ubuntu Server guest on ESXi to Hyper-V?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, vmware-esxi, hyper-v

We desperately need a solution to move a server fro  ESXI to Hyper-V. Server guest is Ubuntu intranet server.

We have tried a few options but this is a critical server and SCVMM is just not recognising it, although we tried this as a p2v (this has worked for Windows machines!).

Answer (score 2):

What options have you used and where is it getting stuck? I.e., the conversion of the drive image format? Because there are a few tools out there that do that, like http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/convert-vmware-files-to-hyper-v-compatible-files/1801 and http://4sysops.com/archives/free-vmdk2vhd-convert-vmware-vmdk-to-hyper-v-vhd/

Or is there a driver issue (you're removing the VMWare tools from the image before the conversion?)